# how to find out the number of pages of the pdf file that user selects in OpenFileDialog in c#?

Tags: c#, filestream, openfiledialog, dialogresult

Hi from Afghanistan 
I am developing a desktop application that sends and recieve fax using a soap message and I need to know the number of pages of the pdf file the user wants to fax.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiples externals libraries to know the number pages of document PDF, when the document was uploaded to server:

**ITEXTSHARP**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

```
private static int getNumberOfPdfPages(string pathDocument)
{
    return new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pathDocument).NumberOfPages;
}
```

**PDFLIB**

http://www.pdflib.com/  - (Method tested in version 6.0.4.0)

```
private static int getNumberOfPdfPages(string pathDocument)
{
    int doc = 0;
    int numPages = 0;

    PDFlib_dotnet.PDFlib oPDF = new PDFlib_dotnet.PDFlib();
    doc = oPDF.open_pdi(pathDocument, "", 0); //open document
    if (doc != -1) //if not problem open document
    {
        numPages = (int)oPDF.get_pdi_value("/Root/Pages/Count", doc, -1, 0);
        oPDF.close_pdi(doc);//close document
    }
    return numPages;
}
```

**PDFSHARP**

```
private static int getNumberOfPdfPages(string pathDocument)
{
    return PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(pathDocument, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.InformationOnly).PageCount;
}
```

**STREAMREADER**

Not need external library

```
public static int getNumberOfPdfPages(string pathDocument)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(pathDocument)))
    {
        return new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]").Matches(sr.ReadToEnd()).Count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a PDF library to parse the PDF and determine the number of pages it contains. There are several [free ones for .NET](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+pdf+library+C%23&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS557US557&oq=free+pdf+library+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5212j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=free%20pdf%20library%20.NET).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find the `/Count` value in the file and just parse that out without using an external library. It'll look like `/Count 5` if the PDF has 5 pages.

I don't know how robust that solution is, but it's definitely worth trying before adding/learning another library.

Answer (score 0):

I used PDFjs to evaluate PDF before uploading on the client side. Works great for getting page count, page size....though the payload for loading the PDFjs is a big heavy

http://www.pdfcharts.com/lab/analyze.html